# Search results in Salesforce app vs Salesforce web app

Tags: salesforce1-app, global-search

I'm just wondering if anyone has had this issue.  When I do a search for a record on either my production environment or Sandbox I get the secondary field listed after the record name, like this:

```
ACME - Location 1
```

If i try the same search in the Salesforce app, I only get this:

```
ACME
```

"Location 1" in the second field in the search layout and as such should be picked up as the secondary field.

Does the app not support the secondary field in search results like it does in the browser?

This is done here on the search on the app front page:

[image]

I have already contacted SF Support but I'd like to know whether anyone has run into the same problem.  I'm fairly certain that the app doesn't support the secondary field but you never know, and support docs don't say anything about it.

Comment: Which search context is this? Search in the Global Search box? Lookup search? Something else?

Comment: Search in the global search box , as seen here:

Comment: this document https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_mobile_sf1_search.htm&type=5 says that "In Salesforce for Android and Salesforce for iOS, search results show the first six fields from the search layout. In Salesforce mobile web, search results show the first four fields." Which mobile app do you use? is Location 1 value of the first six or four fields from the search layout?

Comment: It's the Secondary Field in the field list for the Search Layout for Account, see here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_lookup_config_lex.htm&type=5 and note especially the section called "Notes on the Secondary Field"